# Systemd does not write to StandardOutput with java program

Tags: java, systemd, redirectstandardoutput

I have this service file to start my Java application

```
[Unit]
Description=StorageWebServer

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/opt/StorageWebServer
ExecStart=/opt/java/openjdk/jdk-16.0.2/bin/java -jar /opt/StorageWebServer/StorageWebServer.jar
User=jvmapps
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
StandardOutput=file:/opt/log.log   
StandardError=file:/opt/log2.log


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have reloaded the file, restarted the service but still it is not writing the output to the folder.

Running on Amazon EC2 with Ubuntu

Comment: You might want to try https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: afaics the file is overwritten, not appended to - just sayin' ;)

Comment: @g00se it does not get overwritten because its not being created in the first place. And yes, I have also tried append:... but that did not make a difference

Comment: Did it run/is it running? Does the 'web server' write to stdout or does it write to a log file itself?

Comment: Does the user `jvmapps` has  the correct rights to create the file under `/opt`? It is usually owned by `root`.

Comment: @g00se yes it is actually running and when I check with systemctl status I can see the output of stdout

Comment: @AndersLindgren when checking the status of the service there are no errors showing up that it cannot access the file. I have also tried with a subfolder in /opt where jvmapps definitely had full privileges but that also did not work

Comment: I'm stumped. Just tried one of my own and it worked fine. You'd probably best ask the systemd people ;)

Comment: @MaxB You didn't say which version of Ubuntu you are running.
After reading this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/479669/334602) you might not be on a version that supports `file` or `append`.
If you are using Java why not go with log4j2 or so?